# Need help on searching a document form Sitepage in Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on SharePoint Integration where i am able to success using Microsoft Graph Explorer for a Site search using Drive id.

Here is how i am able search for a Single Site:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!I9A-JY94D0CQp-2TBvsUupBLMUF2SrJHp5VylC7DY8DpCdF-7uQ6NTp6t-MRD8/root/search(q='sharepoint')
```

With this i am able to get the details of the record 'Sharepoint'.

Now i am trying to search in SitePage where we have Documents added. Can anyone please help me the api to be used in Graph Explorer to get the correct result

I am able to SitePage id using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/pages?$filter=name eq 'DevHome.aspx'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Your first query is doing a keyword search against files in a drive. I don't understand how that is applicable to a web page.

Comment: Hi Sir,

My actual requirement is to search for a Document available under Communication Site which is Web page name DevHome.aspx. If this is not able to work with Microsoft Graph Explorer can you please let me know the API so that i can try it in POSTMAN

Answer (score 1):

Your Approach is incorrect.
If you have to search the content of the document library added to a Site page, you need to query the doc library not the Site page. 
Using Graph API you will not be able to search the content in the site page.

Comment: Hi Sir,

So can you please help me out with the API with which i can get the Documents attach in the Site Page ?
I can try in POSTMAN initially later i will try with my Instance. Since i am not a SharePoint Developer it is making me very difficult to understand the API's. My requirement is search a document with the Keyword given from the Site Page Communication Site available in SharePoint

Comment: Your question already includes an example for searching a drive/document library.

Comment: Hi Sir,

Above API Which is mention is able to search from a Site by in my Sharepoint it is Sitepage/Webpage from where i unable to search with above api.